# Integers don't add up

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a method that'll compute the GPA of a specific semester, my problem is after adding the conditional statements the grades wouldn't add to tGrade. Removing the "if"s and "else if"s would fix my problem but it would give the wrong output, so any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

```
public double computeGPA(ArrayList<Course> courseTaken) {
    double cGPA;
    int tGrade = 00;
    int tUnits = 00;

    for (int x=0; x<courseTaken.size(); x++) {
        for(int y=1; y<courseTaken.size(); y++) {
            if(courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=97) {
                courseTaken.get(x).setCGrade(4);
            } else if (courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=89 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=96) {
                courseTaken.get(x).setCGrade(3);
            } else if (courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=80 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=88) {
                courseTaken.get(x).setCGrade(2);
            } else if (courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=74 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=79) {
                courseTaken.get(x).setCGrade(1);
            } else {
                courseTaken.get(x).setCGrade(0);
            }

            tGrade = courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()+courseTaken.get(y).getCGrade();
            tUnits = courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()+courseTaken.get(y).getCUnits();
        }
    }

    cGPA = (tGrade*tUnits)/tUnits;
return cGPA;
}
```

So far the problem is that the code goes straight to the else statement undermining the others. To add, the data is stored in a text file and that every object of Course there has a grade grater than 85.

Comment: Readability hint: try to avoid so many repetitive calls. Use `Course course = courseToken.get(x); int grade = course.getCGrade();` to start with... (And are you sure you really want to modify the value you're reading? That doesn't sound like a good idea - especially as you're then using the same course later... Are you sure you even need nested loops?)

Comment: Or better (since you don't seem to be using the indexes for anything other than retrieving from the list), use for-each loops: `for (Course course : courseTaken)`

Comment: Do not bracket if statements unless absolutely necessary `if(i >= 97) {...} else if(i >= 89 && i <= 96) {...}`, that second && statement is always true and superfluous.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, I was contemplating about modifying the grade values but since I won't be rewriting the text file and will need to read it again I ended up with that, but since you brought it up then I'll go with another approach. Thanks

Comment: if I read your code correctly, after the first loop for `y`, `courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()` will always end up in else block, since you are setting the grade to < 5 by your statements: `courseTaken.get(x).setCGrade(4);`

Comment: @marstran will do, thanks.

Comment: @Helquin this seems to be a logical flaw rather than any technical question to be honest, do try debugging to find your flaws

Comment: @Compass Just to confirm, I don't need to add brackets if the if statement only has one line right? To add I'm expected to use other text files as source of data so I don't think the second && statement will always hold true.

Comment: @dubes Thanks for the insight, I guess I'll be rewriting the whole method if I can't debug it.

Comment: @Helquin always use brackets on if statements for sanity purposes. An accidental `;` in your if statement will kill debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some reading this is what I came up with. Surely not the best way to do it(repetitive calls ,for-each loop might be better and more), I'll continue to improve this though.

```
public double computeGPA(ArrayList<Course> courseTaken) {
    double cGPA;
    double tUnits = 00;
    double tGrade = 00;

    for(int y=0; y<courseTaken.size(); y++) {
        tUnits += courseTaken.get(y).getCUnits();
    }

    for(int x=0; x<courseTaken.size(); x++) {
        if(courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=97) 
            tGrade += courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()*4;
         else if(courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=93 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=96) 
            tGrade += courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()*3.5;
         else if(courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=89 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=92) 
            tGrade += courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()*3;
         else if(courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=85 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=88) 
            tGrade += courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()*2.5;
         else if(courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=80 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=84) 
            tGrade += courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()*2;
         else if(courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=75 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=79) 
            tGrade += courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()*1.5;
         else if(courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()>=70 && courseTaken.get(x).getCGrade()<=74) 
            tGrade += courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()*1;
         else 
            tGrade += courseTaken.get(x).getCUnits()*0;

    }
    cGPA = tGrade/tUnits;

return cGPA;
}//computeGPA
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for readability and efficiency, I'd recommend looking into switch statements instead of using lots of if statements.

For example, instead if:

```
If (x==1){ }
If (x==2){ }
```

...and so on, you can just test a variable, and check using cases.

```
Switch(x){
    case 1: 
          System.out.print("1")
          break;
    case 2:
       System.out.print("2")
         break;
}
```

For however many values you want to test. Sorry if it's not written very well I'm on my phone at the minute.

Comment: My problem with switch statements being used in my code is that the conditions I set are ranges of values(i.e. 93 to 96), not specific values and if I use switch statements then I'd end up with more lines of code. Though I'd consider it if I'm dealing with only around 8 to 10 specific values.